# Is my solution for this question about probability correct? Also, is my interpretation of part c accurate?

Tags: probability

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if my interpretation of part c is correct. Is it saying both are not pictures or spades, as in neither is picture or spade; or is it saying "not pictures" just referring to the pictures?

Comment: In fact the formulation is not clear ! My guess is "neither a spade nor a picture"

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I would lean toward interpreting the question as neither a spade nor a picture card, but the wording of the question could be improved.

Comment: How do you interpret 'not picture cards or spades'- (not picture cards) or spades' or not (picture cards or spades)'?

Comment: As an aside, in my experience I find it much more common to hear to phrase "*face cards*" to refer to jacks, queens and kings rather than "*picture cards.*"

Comment: Given this oddity in using the phrase "*picture cards*" and the frustratingly ambiguous wording, I expect that the author of this problem is not a native English speaker.  It could be "*Neither card is a face card nor a spade*" in which case $J\heartsuit,2\spadesuit$ would not be a valid hand, or it could be "*The cards are not both face cards or the cards are not both spades*" in which case $J\heartsuit,2\spadesuit$ is a valid hand.  It could even be "*The cards are both not face cards or the cards are both not spades.*"  All three of these problems are different.

Comment: Letting $P_1,P_2,S_1,S_2$ represent the events "The first card is a picture card, The second card is a picture card, The first card is a spade card, The second card is a spade card" respectively, I could see any of $P_1^cP_2^cS_1^cS_2^c, P_1^cP_2^c\cup S_1^cS_2^c, (P_1^c\cup P_2^c)\cap (S_1^c\cup S_2^c), P_1^c\cup P_2^c\cup S_1^c\cup S_2^c$ as being the intended event to find the probability for.  "*Both cards are not picture cards nor spades*" is perhaps the least modified phrase which would correspond to $P_1^cP_2^cS_1^cS_2^c$

Comment: Note: The opposite of "*Both are spades*" is "*At least one is not a spade.*"  The opposite is not "*Both are not spades.*"

Answer (score 1):

For (c), I believe that it means that both of the cards are not "picture" cards, *and* that both of them are not spades. Another way you could look at it is by picking one of the two cards randomly. The probability that it is a spade is 0. The probability that it is a "picture" card is 0.

As to your answer to (c), I did not check your math, but here is another way to solve it by simply counting the cards. First of all, we have 52 cards to choose from for our first pick, but 12 of them are face(picture) cards, so we only have 40(52 - 12) cards now. Out of the 40 cards left, 10 of them are spades(Ace ... 10), so we now have only 30(40-10) cards. So for the first card, the probability is 30/52. For the second card, the probability is 29/51, because we took the first card out of all of the cards and we also took one of the desired cards(not face or spades). In conclusion, the probability that both of the cards are not face cards or spades is 30/52 * 29/51 = 870/2652 = 0.328| Hmm, my answer disagrees with yours, so which one is correct? As a rough estimate, your answer is about 9/10, which is more than the probability of the first card(30/52); and multiplying by the probability of the second card(which is less than 1) should not make the probability go up. So I think that my answer is a bit more likely.(Of course the question was a bit confusing, so that is probably why).

P.S. Any corrections or hints welcome.

Comment: can you check my math..because I still believe what I did is correct

Comment: @David: I think the problem is that I interpreted the question differently than you did. My answer is only correct for my interpretation, but it is possibly wrong for yours. Are you thinking it about it like this: The probability that the two cards are not a pair of spades and that they are also not a pair of picture cards?

Comment: yes,thats how i interpreted it

Comment: Spade: 13/52 second: 12/51  +  face: 12/52 second: 11/51   = 156/2652 +  132/2652 = 288/2652 = 0.10859728506 ______ Question: In your 1 - p[...] part, why do you take away some fractions?(- 12/52 * 11/51 * 13/52 * 12/52) What does this represent?